# WebDAV with Apache only working with Ubuntu client

Tags: 10.04, apache2, webdav

WebDAV (via SSL) is configured on a VirtualHost on my root-Server. SSL is working fine with all clients and other applications running below this virtual host are working. Unfortunately WebDAV does not.

Nautilus as Client works well, cadaver as client works only on some (php) files, not on all. An old Internet Explorer 6 is working as well, but recent clients on Mac OS X and Windows do not work.

Both dav-modules are enabled, files and  directories are owned by www-data:www-data and the following excerpt is part of my config (anonymized).

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerName server.example.com

[...]

    # WebDAV
    DavLockDB /srv/dav/lockdb

[...]

    Alias /serendipity "/srv/www/webdav"
    <Directory "/srv/www/webdav">
        DAV on
        ForceType text/plain
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Serendipity Testblog"
        AuthUserFile /srv/pwd/serendipity
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

[...]

</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To add to this: DAV itself is working and shows directories and files, but file retrieval only results in the HTTP-parsed representation of a file. That means, PHP gets parsed and the downloaded file shows the file as if it were viewed inside a Browser.

Answer (score 2):

Add a line beneath the DAVLockDB directive, which says:

```
ForceType text/plain
```

This will tell Apache not to evaluate scripts but answer their file content instead.

Good luck...